# Best practice for reading multiple databases SQLite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

My goal with this project is to create a quiz app that has the ability to quiz from different banks of data. I would like the user to have the option to select which subjects they wish to be tested on, and then once selected the different banks can be combined and randomized for testing purposes. This is my first time utilizing databases and I was wondering if I could get a little input on the most economic way for this to happen. Are multiple tables my best option? Later down the road I hope to implement the ability to keep records of how well was done on each subject. If someone could point me in the right direction or give me suggestions for this I would be very appreciative.

Comment: You can model it using multiple tables. You don't need multiple databases.

Comment: A more clear question would be nice, even if you've provided some background. It just makes it easier to answer.

Comment: But in most cases single database with multiple tables is more efficient.

Comment: Since I do not have a profound knowledge of utilizing sqlite, I cant provide more information at this time. I will do my best to familiarize myself. Thank you for the assistance thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I literally just finished creating my quiz app and I created one table to manage the questions and another to manage the scores. As long as you use a category column, you can set the cursor to read through questions with the categories you've selected. The cursor can return how many questions are in the categories selected, and you can also quite easily shuffle the numbers to get a random assortment of questions. If you've got any specific questions, just ask

(As for the how well people have done, I suggest putting that in another different database. It's easier as that database is probably never going to be upgraded, you don't have to modify it once it is created).

Comment: The only issue I have is that I will have multiple tables for different banks of questions. I want to combine 1-5 tables (different subjects) and still have the ability to randomize the questions.

Comment: I have currently have 22 categories which will go up to 40 soon all in the one table which works amazingly. But if you have to go for multiple tables (for whatever reason), you're going to have to implement several cursors to read each table for how many questions and pass a random table for each call making sure to not to try to fetch a question that has an ID above the number of questions you have. You're also going to have to remember that the chance is that questions from different categories will have the same ID if you auto increment.

Comment: How you did you cycle and randomize the question for 1 table if the user selected question id 1-5, 11-15 and 26-30 for example?

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
number.add(
//add all your numbers here individually
);
Collections.shuffle(number);

Comment: I dont have 15 reputation yet. When I do, I will most definitely haha.